# How to generate call-graphs for given javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, call-graph

I have seen "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385335/how-to-generate-function-call-graphs-for-javascript", and tried it.  It works well, if you want to get an abstract syntax tree.

Unfortunately Closure Compiler only seems to offer `--print_tree`, `--print_ast` and `--print_pass_graph`.  None of them are useful for me.

I want to see a chart of which function calls which other functions.

Comment: Why don't you use the dev tools built in support for profiling javascript?

Comment: It appears the original thread has gone and link is now broken. :-(

Comment: Check this out. https://github.com/cheburakshu/Javascript-Explorer-Callgraph

Comment: The post linked on the question was deleted long ago. A link to its latest archived version can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120907153927/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385335/how-to-generate-function-call-graphs-for-javascript).

Comment: Hi beatak, having gone through all the suggestions, what have you settled with or recommend? Would you give a quick summary here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613726/ please? Thx.

Comment: https://github.com/Persper/js-callgraph seems modern.

Answer (score 21):

[code2flow](https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow) does exactly this. Full disclosure, I started this project

To run

```
$ code2flow source1.js source2.js -o out.gv
```

Then, open out.gv with graphviz

**Edit**: For now, this project is unmaintained. I would suggest trying out a different solution before using code2flow.

Comment: That's awesome. If it can run on jQuery, it must be able to handle my projects as well. I'll definitely try it.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @scottmrogowski, your project worked really well for me.  For anyone else using this solution, I'd like to point out [this page](http://dl9obn.darc.de/programming/python/dottoxml/) which converts graphviz to files that yEd can open.  Scott, I tweaked your python script to name the nodes based on the function names, and it produced great yEd-readable output.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the project went unmaintained. I was unable to make code2flow just working on my Windows and Linux laptop.

Comment: @achille You are right, this is unmaintained and I've now updated my answer. I developed this on a Mac and tested it on both Mac and Debian systems. Windows users have had trouble getting this to work. You might want to verify that you are using Python 2.7x instead of 3.x.

Comment: It works on windows:
1. install graphviz: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/windows/graphviz-2.38.msi
2. ADD below to Windows Environment PATH, i.e.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin
3. cd C:\code2flow-master\code2flow-master
python setup.py install
python code2flow myfile.js -o myfile.jpeg

However it does not understand asyc.parallel, and others in javascript, so its mostly useless for these basic scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

If you filter the output of `closure --print_tree` you get what you want.

For example take the following file:

```
var fib = function(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
};

console.log(fib(fib(5)));
```

Filter the output of `closure --print_tree`

```
            NAME fib 1 
                FUNCTION  1 
                                    CALL 5 
                                        NAME fib 5 
                                        SUB 5 
                                            NAME a 5 
                                            NUMBER 1.0 5 
                                    CALL 5 
                                        NAME fib 5 
                                        SUB 5 
                                            NAME a 5 
                                            NUMBER 2.0 5 
        EXPR_RESULT 9 
            CALL 9 
                GETPROP 9 
                    NAME console 9 
                    STRING log 9 
                CALL 9 
                CALL 9 
                    NAME fib 9 
                    CALL 9 
                    CALL 9 
                        NAME fib 9 
                        NUMBER 5.0 9
```

And you can see all the call statements.

I wrote the following scripts to do this.

`./call_tree`

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
function make_tree() {
    closure --print_tree $1 | grep $1
}

function parse_tree() {
    gawk -f parse_tree.awk
}

if [[ "$1" = "--tree" ]]; then
    make_tree $2
else
    make_tree $1 | parse_tree
fi
```

`parse_tree.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    lines_c = 0
    indent_width = 4
    indent_offset = 0
    string_offset = ""
    calling = 0
    call_indent = 0
}

{
    sub(/\[source_file.*$/, "")
    sub(/\[free_call.*$/, "")
}

/SCRIPT/ {
    indent_offset = calculate_indent($0)
    root_indent = indent_offset - 1
}

/FUNCTION/ {
    pl  = get_previous_line()
    if (calculate_indent(pl) < calculate_indent($0))
        print pl
    print
}

{
    lines_v[lines_c] = $0
    lines_c += 1
}

{
    indent = calculate_indent($0)
    if (indent <= call_indent) {
        calling = 0
    }
    if (calling) {
        print
    }
}

/CALL/ {
    calling = 1
    call_indent = calculate_indent($0)
    print
}

/EXPR/{
    line_indent = calculate_indent($0)
    if (line_indent == root_indent) {
        if ($0 !~ /(FUNCTION)/) {
            print
        }
    }
}

function calculate_indent(line) {
    match(line, /^ */)
    return int(RLENGTH / indent_width) - indent_offset
}

function get_previous_line() {
    return lines_v[lines_c - 1]
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting approach. I'll dig around a bit more, but thanks!!

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the line number of each function call that is evaluated in a script?

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed this using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) and [Dot/GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/Documentation.php), in a sort of combination of the above answer and the answers to the linked question.

The missing part, for me, was how to filter the parsed AST. It turns out that UglifyJS has the TreeWalker object, which basically applys a function to each node of the AST. This is the code I have so far:

```
//to be run using nodejs
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js')
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');

var file = 'path/to/file...';
//read in the code
var code = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
//parse it to AST
var toplevel = UglifyJS.parse(code);
//open the output DOT file
var out = fs.openSync('path/to/output/file...', 'w');
//output the start of a directed graph in DOT notation
fs.writeSync(out, 'digraph test{\n');

//use a tree walker to examine each node
var walker = new UglifyJS.TreeWalker(function(node){
    //check for function calls
    if (node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Call) {
        if(node.expression.name !== undefined)
        {
        //find where the calling function is defined
        var p = walker.find_parent(UglifyJS.AST_Defun);

        if(p !== undefined)
        {
            //filter out unneccessary stuff, eg calls to external libraries or constructors
            if(node.expression.name == "$" || node.expression.name == "Number" || node.expression.name =="Date")
            {
                //NOTE: $ is from jquery, and causes problems if it's in the DOT file.
                //It's also very frequent, so even replacing it with a safe string
                //results in a very cluttered graph
            }
            else
            {

                fs.writeSync(out, p.name.name);
                fs.writeSync(out, " -> ");
                fs.writeSync(out, node.expression.name);
                fs.writeSync(out, "\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //it's a top level function
            fs.writeSync(out, node.expression.name);
            fs.writeSync(out, "\n");
        }

    }
}
if(node instanceof UglifyJS.AST_Defun)
{
    //defined but not called
    fs.writeSync(out, node.name.name);
    fs.writeSync(out, "\n");
}
});
//analyse the AST
toplevel.walk(walker);

//finally, write out the closing bracket
fs.writeSync(out, '}');
```

I run it with [node](http://nodejs.org/), and then put the output through

`dot -Tpng -o graph_name.png dot_file_name.dot`

Notes:

It gives a pretty basic graph - only black and white and no formatting.

It doesn't catch ajax at all, and presumably not stuff like `eval` or `with` either, as [others have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746719/1856824).

Also, as it stands it includes in the graph: functions called by other functions (and consequently functions that call other functions), functions that are called independantly, AND functions that are defined but not called.

As a result of all this, it may miss things that are relevant, or include things that are not. It's a start though, and appears to accomplish what I was after, and what led me to this question in the first place.

Comment: Interesting. It does make a call graph for a simple javascript.  Thanks for your efforts!  (side note: Recently I started to dig this area with Esprima http://esprima.org/ and Esprima is so interesting.)

Comment: @beatak Did you manage to generate similar graphs with esprima?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS
gives access to an ast in javascript.

ast.coffee

```
util = require 'util'
jsp = require('uglify-js').parser

orig_code = """

var a = function (x) {
  return x * x;
};

function b (x) {
  return a(x)
}

console.log(a(5));
console.log(b(5));

"""

ast = jsp.parse(orig_code)

console.log util.inspect ast, true, null, true
```