# Get inside function calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to give a abroad picture from my question. Suppose I have a function, inside this function I have some other function calls and finally, first function returns a value.

```
function a() {
  return 1;
}

function b() {
  var result = a();
  return 2 + result;
}

b();
```

Now, after calling b() method, I want to know how many and what functions called inside the b() function. How can I achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182387/any-tools-to-draw-call-graphs-for-given-javascript might give you some glues.

Comment: Do you want to know it for debugging or to create program logic with it? The latter would be a bad design decision, as it would violate the [concept of encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) - only the function is responsible for what happens inside it

Comment: @Bergi, It would definitely be a bad design but why would it violate the concept of encapsulation?

Comment: It would be better if @Afshin shares why he wants such a feature because it seems like there is no generic, out of the box and elegant way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no orthodox method for doing this. You can do the opposite, however, find out who called the function a() by accessing it's `arguments.callee.caller` inside a().

But, if you are real serious about finding out what functions are called within your function, you can always do `b.toString()` and then parse the code manually :)

Comment: `b.toString()` isn't too helpful if `b` comes from a scope that is inaccessible :-)

Comment: I am assuming we are working from the outer scope of this example.

Answer (score 0):

You need an AST generator. Use a javascript parser like [this](http://boshi.inimino.org/3box/PanPG/build/js_ast.html#simple).