# Call graph creator based on JS file / snippet

Tags: javascript, call-graph

This is a very old question, but most answers from 2009 are outdated.
As e.g. [How to generate call-graphs for given javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182387/how-to-generate-call-graphs-for-given-javascript)

Using Google, I also found on npm this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/callgraph but it's not maintained and doesn't work.

So, I'm bringing this after a couple of years up again to see if anyone has created something to make a simple call graph based on a js file or a code snippet?

---

**Edit**:

Well after couple of months, I still havn't found anything. The closest i came was this [JS Code to SVG Flowchart](https://bogdan-lyashenko.github.io/js-code-to-svg-flowchart/docs/live-editor/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get `callgraph` from NPM to work either, but I've been having better luck with `js-callgraph`, which was updated this year (2019). It doesn't generate visual output, but you'll get a JSON data structure that can be piped into other graphing tools like Gephi or Graphviz.

https://github.com/Persper/js-callgraph