# Print javascript function tree

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need to parse some javascript code and print a tree of function
declarations and calls (and nothing else).

Something like this:

```
function test3()

function test()
  declares 
    function test2()
      calls test3()
  calls test2()
```

What is the fastest and easies way to do this ?
I have multiple functions and files.

I've tried using Antlr, spent 2 days and finally gave up,
it's too complicated for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this reference,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182387/how-to-generate-call-graphs-for-given-javascript[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182387/how-to-generate-call-graphs-for-given-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[Esprima](http://esprima.org/) is a JavaScript parser that allows you to get the information you're looking for.