# How to generate call-graphs for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, call-graph

Following up on [How to generate call-graphs for given javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182387/), which was closed because it needs to focus on *"one problem only"*, so here is my focus --

How to generate the callgraph for my nodejs Javascript program?

I wrote it myself, and used class inherit and inherit and inherit..., but that's a while ago, and I am never a Javascript programmer in the first place, so I need to know what's going on.

The solution to the about question, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385335/how-to-generate-function-call-graphs-for-javascript" no longer exist any more. So I'm thinking better try to ask it again.

I did some research and found some tool called [JavaScript Studio](https://medium.com/javascript-studio/visualizing-call-trees-c3a68865853a) can do it, but am really wonder whether it comes to the top because of widely acceptance, or just it did a good job in SEO. So, again,

How to generate a call tree for nodejs programs that used lots of nested `require`s and nested class inheritances?

I don't mind the best of breed approach (e.g., hand-crafting some `js/awk` scripts to glue things together and view with `graphviz`), and would avoid huge tools/installations for this seldom-used task if possible.

Comment: "*this seldom-used task*" - you nailed it. Also JavaScript is quite hard to statically analyse. I doubt there are many tools doing this.

Comment: @Bergi installation of an operating system is a seldom-used task and yet there are plenty of answered questions for that.  There are also plenty of hard to perform tasks that have questions and answers.

Comment: @xpt unfortunately the link you've provided results in a 410 error (author deleted).

Comment: If you meant "JavaScript Studio" then forgot about it -- if it had been the answer, I wouldn't have asked the question @Jeff.